Remove [tag:math]?
I think that the math doesn't serve a clear purpose: The meaning of the Math-Tag seems to range from statistics, over exchange-rate to cryptograpy. It only appears as a single tag in one falsely tagged question.
Either the purpose of math has to be clarified or it should be deleted.

Removing it sounds good to me.

Alright, I will be getting right to it.
